# Arduino webclient

Tags: php, apache, arduino, webclient

I'm having some practice with arduino. I'm trying to send get request to my local webserver and get it's answer. Byt webserver answering with additional headers, and I can`t parse var to do somthing with it.
Here is webserver answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2013 17:44:36 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=26va2lddtjdh9m18mjeh2lq9s1; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

0
```

I need to read only switch status: 0, but get a lot of headers before.
How can I get only server answer to var without headers?

Answer (score 1):

Headers are separated from the body of a HTTP response by a `\r\n\r\n` sequence. Read and discard the output until that particular sequence is found, from that point you will be reading the body of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is manage the request on server side creating a RESTful webservice that returns only the data with no headers. In this case you have a smaller package to be sent to Arduino and it needs less processing efforts.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you are looking for something like this:
https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient
It is a parser for Arduino, with this you can do:

```
EthernetClient c;
HttpClient http(c);
err = http.get(kHostname, kPath);
err = http.responseStatusCode();
err = http.skipResponseHeaders();
```

And you don't have to parse the response yourself.
Hope it helps!